# Azure User Key & Secret rather than multiple SAS

Tags: azure

I am trying to move files [json, csv, etc] into Azure Blob Storage, then load the data into Synapse. There are several blob accounts I am landing data into, then running scripts to copy into Synapse. I have been able to do this with a SAS, but it seems that I need one for each Blob account.

My permissions allow me to access all of these accounts/services in the Azure portal - is there a generic user key/secret I should be using so I do not have to create/access a SAS each time I process a transaction?

Comment: There is no single generic user key/secret - every storage account has its own keys (and the same SAS doesn't apply across storage accounts). However, I would suggest looking into Azure AD, which might be relevant for you.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use a Service Principal for uploading purpose?